# Javascript for IE users is executed in others browsers but not IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

From [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411551/if-browser-is-internet-explorer-run-an-alternative-script-instead) I found that the code below can determine if a user has IE, and then run js-code specific to them. But when I used the code on my site, the effect was the opposite. On other browsers the code is fired, on IE not.
What am I doing wrong?

```
<![if !IE]>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".box.2").fadeOut(1500);
});
</script>

<![endif]>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `!` in front of `IE` - it reverses the sense of the test and means *don't* do this on IE!

To ensure that other browsers ignore the text, write the comment thus:

```
<!--[if IE]>
...
<![endif]-->
```

NB: Microsoft have dropped support for conditional comments when using IE 10 in full HTML5 mode.

Comment: I changed it to "<![if IE]>", but now the code is executed in both IE and Chrome

Comment: Could it be that I have <![if IE]> in the body-section?

Answer (score 0):

Change `<![if !IE]>` to `<![if IE]>`

Answer (score 0):

It's quite logical: when you check `<![if !IE]>`, your branching on `!IE`, not Internet Explorer, just drop the `!`: `<![if IE]>` and you're good to go. Like I'm ok to post this answer, having typed a sufficient amount of chars