# Conditional IE statement - run script

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

I have a lame problem:

If I use something like:

```
<!--[if IE]>
     Random text
<![endif]-->
```

and I open page in IE (9) I naturally see the text "Random text". Everything is ok.

If I use:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("aaa);
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Nothing happens.

I need to run a specific script for IE... can any1 help me with it?

Comment: Is that a syntax error I see: ` alert("aaa);` (missing close quote)

Comment: @zozo: This is question is unlikely to help anyone in the future (it's a simple typo), you might flag it and ask the moderators to remove it.

Comment: By the way @zozo, you should have got an error in the console for this script, did you look for errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your Javascript. Try this:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("aaa");
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Yeah, that was a miss-type :). Srry for lame question. Put some minuses into it so I learn to check my spelling before asking something ;).

Comment: @zozo. But why did you edit the question, now the answer doesn't make sense!

Comment: @zozo: Definitely don't fix it in the question.

Comment: I edited because I thought my " didn't work here but i had the same problem in the script. Need to change the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Use the script to check if it's IE.
EDIT: actually check out some of the [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411551/if-browser-is-internet-explorer-run-an-alternative-script-instead), they're exactly what you want.
For example one person posted this solution which uses a very different approach

```
<script>runFancy = true;</script>
<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    runFancy = false;
 </script> // <div>The HTML version for IE went here</div>
<![endif]-->
```