# <!--[if !IE]> is not working as expected in this case

Tags: html, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

I'm having trouble getting

```
<!--[if !IE]>
```

to work. I'm wondering if it is because I have this in my document

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie6 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

When I add

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/no-ie.css" />
<!--<![endif]-->
```

to my header for some reason, it doesn't work. However, if I add

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <style>
        All my CSS content in here
    </style>
    <!--<![endif]-->
```

to the actual HTML page (in the header) it works.

How can I fix it?

When I removed `<!-->`, I only checked in [Internet Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) (IE) which was working, but now back in Firefox the *no-ie.css* file had been applied to Firefox too. So I added back in the `<!-->` and removed the `/` (and added that into the main template so the [CMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) wouldn't add it back in) and all is working back in Firefox, but now the style sheet is being applied to IE!

So I tried

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/no-ie.css">
<![endif]-->
```

and

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/no-ie.css">
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

And that didn't work.

Basically I'm trying to get this page to work: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ResponsiveTables/responsive.php. But move the CSS content into a style sheet. Surely it's got to be simple. What am I missing? I'd rather not use jQuery if I don't have to.

Comment: You don't need the `<!-->` immediately after the `<!--[if !IE]>`

Comment: Note: if IE only works up to IE9.

Comment: Some people left funny IF IE messages on some pages.

Comment: @cameronjonesweb can you link a reference please otherwise statements like these are not as useful?

Comment: @trainoasis, I could, except my comment is _5 years old_

Answer (score 249):

```
<!--[if !IE]><!--><script src="zepto.min.js"></script><!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]><script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

Note: These conditional comments are 
[no longer supported from IE 10 onwards](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: As of June 2013, this is the *only* correct answer on this page.

Comment: Is this line missing a closing angle bracket? Should it not be:

<!--[if !IE]><!--><script src="zepto.min.js"></script><!--><![endif]-->

Comment: @JohnB - can you explain why `<!--[if lt IE 9]>` is not going to work?

Comment: This, along with all the other conditional comments solutions, will not detect IE 10 / IE 11

Comment: It does not work in IE 11, it loads script, even if condition is !IE

Comment: @Giedrius From IE10 on, conditional comments are **no longer supported**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I also used the code above to edit to: <!--[if !IE 8]><!--> so to not target ie8 specifically. Used this for adding in jQuery versions on older updated project. Works a treat, thank you.

Comment: Also, this is not valid HTML. For example with Tomcat there is this error: The string "--" is not permitted within comments.

Comment: This works only if you simulate IE9 behaviour, using this right after the html tag

```<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">```

Comment: @Lawrence Wagerfield: The user never learned how to accept answers during their time on the site. And they haven't been seen in years. Tough luck.

Comment: @n00shie: The closing angle bracket is not necessary there. It won't change how the comment is parsed by any browser.

Comment: @Christian Romeni: Tomcat is lying - the string -- doesn't appear anywhere in any of the comments. This is certainly valid HTML.

Comment: IE11.0 seems to ignore <!--[if IE]><script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script><![endif]-->

Comment: This is the only way that worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21712356/6525081

Comment: This helped me solved a peculiar problem with Edge with a page preloader. Thank you!

Answer (score 71):

Browsers other than Internet Explorer treat the conditional statements as comments because they're enclosed inside comment tags.

```
<!--[if IE]>
Non-Internet Explorer browsers ignore this
<![endif]-->
```

However, when you're targeting a browser that is *Internet Explorer not* Internet Explorer, you have to use two comments, one before and one after the code. Internet Explorer will ignore the code between them, whereas other browsers will treat it as normal code. The syntax for targeting non-Internet Explorer browsers is therefore:

```
<!--[if !IE]-->
Internet Explorer ignores this
<!--[endif]-->
```

Note: These conditional comments are [no longer supported from Internet Explorer 10 onwards](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: That's great. Thanks for that. The stylesheet works however the problem I have now is that at the top of the page above the header this appears in ie <!--[if !IE]--> <!--[endif]--> (the tag went in the header area not body)

Comment: -1: This answer is *incorrect* because `<!--[if !IE]-->IE ignores this<!--[endif]-->` is **not** hidden from IE! (7, 8, or 9)

Comment: None of the answers worked for me, perhaps something changed in the recent release of IE10 (tried in IE9 mode too). - All attempts ended up reaching the !IE section on all browsers (IE and not IE).

Comment: IE10 does not support conditional statements.

Comment: Be aware of whitespaces in <!--[if IE]> and <![endif]--> - there shouldn't be any whitespaces (e.g. between !-- and [. It doesn't work with whitespaces.

Comment: The negative statement (the second one in the answer) is wrong and needs to look like this to hide from IE<=9: `<!--[if !IE]> -->
IE ignores this
<!-- <![endif]-->`. This is an alternative syntax to:  `<!--[if !IE]><!--> IE ignores this <!--<![endif]-->`.

Comment: Well, that was annoying... Thank you for the clarification

Comment: I spoke too soon, I had to do `<!--[if IE]-->...<!--[endif]-->` for IE and `<!--[if !IE]-->...<!--[endif]-->` for FF, Chrome, etc

Answer (score 40):

Reasons for why the Internet Explorer targeting doesn’t work: [Internet Explorer 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11#Internet_Explorer_10) and onward no longer support conditional comments. From the Microsoft official website:

> Support for conditional comments has been removed in Internet Explorer
> 10 standards and quirks modes for improved interoperability and
> compliance with HTML5.

Please see here for more details: *[Conditional comments are no longer supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/hh801214(v=vs.85))*.

If you desperately need to target Internet Explorer, you can use this jQuery code to add an `ie` class to  and then use the `.ie` class in your CSS to target Internet Explorer browsers.

```
if ($.browser.msie) {
    $("html").addClass("ie");
}
```

`$.browser` is not available after jQuery 1.9. If you upgrade to jQuery above 1.9 or you already use it, you can include the jQuery migration script after jQuery so that it adds missing parts:
[jQuery Migrate Plugin](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-migrate-plugin)

Alternatively, please check this question for possible workarounds: *[browser.msie error after update to jQuery 1.9.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892095/browser-msie-error-after-update-to-jquery-1-9-1)*

Comment: that's a real nice solution! I don't even need to use it on the dom tree to apply certain classes.

Comment: Please note, this is deprecated since jQuery 1.3 and removed in 1.9

Answer (score 13):

The Microsoft-recommended syntax for downlevel-revealed conditional “comments” is this:

```
<![if !IE]>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/no-ie.css" />
<![endif]>
```

These aren’t comments, but they work properly.

Comment: Found this link that supports this answer, also has lots of other info that could help the thread, I think this is an important subject...only difference I see is if a hidden or revealed syntax is used and I am not sure how this will effect other browsers...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.ASPX

Comment: Note: These conditional comments are [no longer supported from IE 10 onwards](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 11):

I use this and it works:

```
<!--[if !IE]><!--> if it is not IE <!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: This results in Firefox just treating the entire contents as a comment for me. @Charmander solution worked for both IE and Firefox - <![if !IE]><![endif]>

Comment: Note: These conditional comments are [no longer supported from IE 10 onwards](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 8):

First of all, the right syntax is:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/ie6.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Try these posts:

- *[Conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)*
- *[How To Create an IE-Only Stylesheet](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)*

Another thing you can do:

Check the browser with jQuery:

```
if($.browser.msie) { // Do something... }
```

In this case you can change CSS rules for some elements or add
a new CSS link reference:

Read this: *[Applying stylesheets dynamically with jQuery](http://rickardnilsson.net/post/2008/08/02/Applying-stylesheets-dynamically-with-jQuery.aspx)*

Comment: See user1324409's answer above for a more accurate answer.

Comment: Due to the jQuery updates, anybody who uses $.browser.msie, will have to include jquery-migrate.js and then this will work.

Comment: Note: These conditional comments are [no longer supported from IE 10 onwards](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: The link provided in the answer is dead.

Answer (score 8):

You need to add a space for the `<!-- [if !IE] -->`. My full CSS block goes as follows, since IE8 is terrible with media queries.

```
<!-- IE 8 or below -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="/Resources/css/master1300.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!-- IE 9 or above -->
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="(max-width: 100000px) and (min-width:481px)"
    href="/Resources/css/master1300.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="(max-width: 480px)"
    href="/Resources/css/master480.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!-- Not IE -->
<!-- [if !IE] -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="(max-width: 100000px) and (min-width:481px)"
    href="/Resources/css/master1300.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="(max-width: 480px)"
    href="/Resources/css/master480.css" />
<!-- [endif] -->
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but if I use 
     <!-- [if !IE] -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/no-ie.csss" />
     <!-- [endif] -->
then other browsers apply this too.

Comment: Isn't that the point, to have other browsers apply that section?

Comment: -1:  The `!IE` technique mentioned here will actually execute the commented block for IE 7 through 10.

Comment: Note: These conditional comments are [no longer supported from IE 10 onwards](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 8):

**For targeting Internet Explorer users:**

```
<!--[if IE]>
Place content here for users of Internet Explorer.
<![endif]-->
```

**For targeting all others:**

```
<![if !IE]>
Place content here for Users of all other browsers.
<![endif]>
```

The *conditional comments* can only be detected by Internet Explorer. All other browsers treat it as normal comments.

To target [Internet Explorer 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_6), [Internet Explorer 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_7), etc. You have to use "greater than equal" or "lesser than (equal)" in the *if* Statement. Like this:

***Greater than or equal:***

```
<!--[if gte IE 7]>
Place content here for users of Internet Explorer 7 or above.
<![endif]-->
```

***Lesser than:***

```
<!--[if lt IE 6]>
Place content here for users of Internet Explorer 5 or lower.
<![endif]-->
```

[Source: mediacollege.com](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/html/detect/detect-ie.html)

Comment: Note: These conditional comments are [no longer supported from IE 10 onwards](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 8):

**This is for until [Internet Explorer 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_9)**:

```
<!--[if IE ]>
    <style>
        .someclass{
            text-align: center;
            background: #00ADEF;
            color: #FFF;
            visibility: hidden;  // In case of hiding
        }
        #someotherclass{
            display: block !important;
            visibility: visible; // In case of visible
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

**This is for after Internet Explorer 9**

```
  @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {Enter your CSS here}
```

Answer (score 5):

For the [Internet Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer) browser:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Unicode">
<![endif]-->
```

For all non-Internet Explorer browsers:

```
<![if !IE]>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf8">
<![endif]>
```

For all Internet Explorer versions greater than [Internet Explorer 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8) *or* all non-Internet Explorer browsers:

```
<!--[if (gt IE 8)|!(IE)]><!--><script src="/_JS/library/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script><!--<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 3):

A conditional comment is a comment that starts with `<!--[if IE]>` which couldn't be read by any browser except Internet Explorer.

From 2011, conditional comments aren’t supported starting form [Internet Explorer 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11#Internet_Explorer_10) as announced by Microsoft in that time: *[Conditional comments are no longer supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/hh801214(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)*

The only option to use the *conditional comments* is to request Internet Explorer to run your site as [Internet Explorer 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_9) which supports the conditional comments.

You can write your own CSS and/or JavaScript files for Internet Explorer only and other browsers won't load or execute it.

This code snippet shows how to make [Internet Explorer 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11#Internet_Explorer_10) or [Internet Explorer 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11#Internet_Explorer_11) run *ie-only.css* and *ie-only.js* which contains custom codes to solve Internet Explorer compatibility issues.

```
    <html>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
      <!--[if IE]>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=Unicode">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='/css/ie-only.css' />
            <script src="/js/ie-only.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me across all Internet Explorer versions greater than version 6 ([Internet Explorer 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_7), [Internet Explorer 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8), [Internet Explorer 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_9), [Internet Explorer 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11#Internet_Explorer_10), etc., [Chrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) 3 up to what it is now, and [Firefox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Firefox) version 3 up to what it is now):

```js
// Test if running in Internet Explorer or not
function isIE () {
    var myNav = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    return (myNav.indexOf('msie') != -1 || myNav.indexOf('trident') != -1) ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are working with IE 10 or above, as mentioned in http://tanalin.com/en/articles/ie-version-js/ the conditional comments are no longer supported. 
You might refer to https://gist.github.com/jasongaylord/5733469 as an alternative method, which the Trident version is checked as well from the navigator.userAgent. This also verified in case the browser is working in compatibility mode.

Answer (score 1):

[Thank you Fernando68](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785587/if-ie-is-not-working-as-expected-in-this-case/40795918#40795918). I used this:

```javascript
function isIE () {
     var myNav = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
     return (myNav.indexOf('msie') != -1 || myNav.indexOf('trident') != -1) ? true : false;
}

if(isIE()){
     $.getScript('js/script.min.js', function() {
            alert('Load was performed.');
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this JavaScript code to detect an Internet Explorer browser:

```javascript
if (navigator.appVersion.toUpperCase().indexOf("MSIE") != -1 ||
    navigator.appVersion.toUpperCase().indexOf("TRIDENT") != -1 ||
    navigator.appVersion.toUpperCase().indexOf("EDGE") != -1)
{
    $("#ie-warning").css("display", "block");
}
```