# Working with jQuery when there is no Internet connection

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am completely new to jQuery. When working with jQuery, I disconnected the Internet to check if my webpage works fine without an Internet connection. It displayed some thing which is not required. When I saw the source code, it displayed:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jquery.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/css/base.css?v=1">
```

So I downloaded the code and kept it in my root folder. Still it's not working well. Can we work with jQuery while offline?

Here is my code:

```html
<!doctype html>

<!-- [if IE 7 ]>                  <html class="no-js ie ie7 lte7 lte8 lte9" lang="en-US"> <![endif] -->
<!-- [if IE 8 ]>                  <html class="no-js ie ie8 lte8 lte9" lang="en-US"> <![endif] -->
<!-- [if IE 9 ]>                  <html class="no-js ie ie9 lte9>" lang="en-US"> <![endif] -->
<!-- [if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]> <!-- > <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif] -->

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title> Home</title>
        <meta name="author" content="jQuery Foundation - jquery.org">
        <meta name="description" content="jQuery: The Write Less, Do More, JavaScript Library">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jquery.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/css/base.css?v=1">
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!--[if lt IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css"><![endif]-->
        <script>try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
        <meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.5.1" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <p class="chromeframe">You are using an outdated browser.
        <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">Upgrade your browser today</a>
        or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">install
        Google Chrome Frame</a> to better experience this site.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <header>
            <section id="global-nav">
                <nav>
                    <div class="constrain">
                        <ul class="links">
                            <li><a href="home.jsp">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown"><a href="CreatPatient.jsp">Patient</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="CreatePatient.jsp">Create Patient</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="Edit Patient">Edit Patient</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown"><a href="Appointments.jsp">Appointments</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="CreateAppointments.jsp">Create Appointments</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="EditAppointments.jsp/">Edit Appointments</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Reports</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="PreOperative.jsp">Pre Operative</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="IntraOperative.jsp">Intra Operative</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="PostOperative.jsp">PostOperative</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </section>
        </header>
    </body>

</html>
```

When I remove this line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jquery.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/css/base.css?v=1">
```

It creates a problem.

I have downloaded jQuery and kept on the desktop. The HTML file is also on the desktop. Why is it not working?

Comment: Have up updated your reference to point to the downloaded file?

Comment: you will need to host it yourself

Comment: Do you really think it works when you disconnect from the internet? The stylesheet are cached so, it works try refreshing with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd>. If then it ok it is really ok. If you want to see it locally then you should download all the assets.

Comment: @silentboy it does not work when its not connected to internet

Comment: *"[These conditional comments are no longer supported from IE 10 onwards.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785587/if-ie-is-not-working-as-expected-in-this-case/14555015#14555015)"*

Comment: *[Conditional comments are no longer supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/hh801214(v=vs.85))* - *"Support for conditional comments has been removed in Internet Explorer 10 standards and quirks modes for improved interoperability and compliance with HTML5"*

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You've mentioned that you downloaded the file - that's a good first step, but you also have to change all the `href` and `src` references.

For example,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jquery.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/css/base.css?v=1">
```

should become

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css">
```

---

Also remember to get the offline version of the jQuery JS library, too:
Download [jquery.js](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js), put it in your root folder & reference it:

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

And if you want it in a subdirectory:

```
<script src="[subdirectory-name]/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

---

Remember that **both files** need to be offline and in your working local directory. This means that you **cannot remove the stylesheet *nor* the jQuery JS library**. Keep both of them, in the local formats I've mentioned above.

Also, putting the `<script>` tag in the `<head>` is bad practice; move it just before the `</body>` tag instead.

---

Your code should now look (in short, note that I haven't put much) like:

```html
...
<html class="no-js" lang="en-US">
<head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css">
    ...
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Again, make sure that `base.css` and `jquery.min.js` are the **exact file names** and are **in the same folder as this `.html` file**

Comment: @albertxing nice answer, I was writing an answer just like this but you 1) got in before me, with 2) a better answer. Very clearly explained. You also mentioned downloading the jQuery library too. +1

Comment: @JavaCoding - updated answer, remember to **keep both files** in local.

Comment: @albertxing both the files are in desktop. If possible can you please change the code that i have posted

Comment: is it possible to embed jquery both online and offline @AlbertXing

Comment: It is! As long as you have jQuery downloaded, referencing it locally in the script tag should work offline or online. Not sure if that's what you were asking @abhishek

Answer (score 2):

Download jQuery and link to it like so:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.css">
```

Answer (score 2):

It will not work if you don't have an Internet connection. To work locally you should copy jquery.js to your local directory and use a relative path.

```
<script src="/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

To work offline with jQuery, just copy the jquery.js file and place it in your local directory. In the script tag, change the *src* attribute:

```
<script src="/path/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution will be to serve the files via localhost. This post explains this in detail.

http://www.wingoku.com/2016/02/accessing-javascriptjquery-script-files.html

Comment: The link is broken (domain expired?): *"Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site. We can’t connect to the server at www.wingoku.com."*

Answer (score -2):

Try *[Initializr](http://www.initializr.com/)*.

It's an HTML5 templates generator to help you getting started with a new project. There is a script which loads the web jQuery file if there is an Internet connection. If there isn't any Internet connection, it takes the local one.

Comment: This is not really answering the problem @JavaCoding is stuck with. If you read the question carefully you'll see he already has a template. So there is no need to initialise a new template.