# Infinite scrolling doesn't work offline

Tags: jquery, offline-browsing, jquery-jscroll

I am trying to learn jQuery and particularly jScroll from real examples. I found [this website](http://endless.horse/) that might look silly to you but it's dead simple so it's a great example of jScroll work for me.

The problem happens when I try to save the web page (Ctrl+S or just Save Page As) to my computer for offline use. The scrolling doesn't work. It's just a static page. I've tried it both in Chrome and Firefox.

Does this happen to you too? And if it does, is there an easy explanation of why it doesn't work?

Comment: Browsers often disable Javascript when displaying locally saved files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15872414/working-with-jquery-when-there-is-no-internet-connection

Comment: As I seen they are using direct jquery api for there resources so first you have to download the js files and then use it in offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr The horse's legs are dynamically added via ajax requests from `http://endless.horse/` which is a cross-origin http request and is therefore restricted for browser security reasons. Also, you would need to be running a server to allow for ajax requests.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

When the scroll event is fired it pulls in `http://endless.horse/legs.html` and appends it to the html to continuously "grow" the legs. There are two reasons it doesn't work locally:

1. Cross-origin HTTP Requests are disallowed for security reasons. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr
2. You need to be running the html file through an HTTP server to have ajax working. After saving the page and opening it, the url begins with something like this `file:///` - That's because you're opening the file directly and not running it through a web-server.

If you're running OSX or Linux you can create a simple server using python.
1. Open up your terminal
2. `cd /path/to/horse/project`
3. `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 5000`
4. visit http://localhost:5000/

On Windows, download [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) and follow instructions.

Instead of using the "Save As" feature, create a new `index.html` at the root of the folder being served. View source on http://endless.horse/ copy/paste that into your new file. The "Save As" feature does a lot of editing on the saved HTML file. You'll have to do this and make sure the `index.html` file links correctly to `jquery.jscroll.js` and the `legs.html` file.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I understand it much better.