# conditional comments not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am extreamly new to HTML,

my goal is to set a global js variable to true when my website is running on IE.

I started by writing

```
<script> var runningIE = false;</script>
<!--[if IE ]>
    Special instructions for IE here
    <script> runningIE = true;</script>
<![endif]-->
```

no matter where I put this code (header, body) I don't see  `Special instructions for IE here` printed anywhere not runningIE would be set to true on IE.

What am I missing here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [<!--\[if !IE\]> not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785587/if-ie-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably testing in IE 10, which does not support conditional comments (browser sniffing is not a good idea in the first place, and IE has improved a lot since the days when it was useful to throw a huge pile of IE specific fixes into a condcom).

Comment: Use feature detection instead of browser detection.

Comment: There are still [a lot of cases](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/Undetectables) where UA sniffing is useful. Alternatively, use [conditional compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/121hztk3%28v=vs.94%29.aspx).