# Failing to load css for FF from MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am creating an MVC 4 application. The styles are working partially across the browsers. However i set this working good for IE. But many styles which works well in IE are failing in Mozilla. I have the following code in my _Layout.html.

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <!--[if IE]>@Styles.Render("~/Content/common.css")<![endif]-->
    <!--[if !IE]>@Styles.Render("~/Content/MozSite.css") <![endif]-->
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

when i load FF, it is not picking the MozSite.css. How do i load this FF dynamically?

Comment: what is the FF version?

Comment: 24.0 is the current version

Comment: I thought only IE interpreted the `<!--[if ...>` comment conditionals and that other browsers ignored them entirely.

Comment: [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785587/if-ie-not-working) is may be helpful.