# <!--if !IE> Not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I'm almost done building my first official site and IE is being annoying. Every time i add

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="c:\Users\Saleh\Desktop\Abid\css\stylesheet.css" />
<!--<![endif]-->
```

to my head the website 'breaks' and IE stops reading the new stylesheet i created

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="c:\Users\Saleh\Desktop\Abid\css\stylesheet2.css">
```

and instead reads the stylesheet inside the `if !IE`.

1. Why?
2. How do I fix this?

*stylesheet2 is for IE and stylesheet is for all other browsers

Comment: Why not use "if IE" for the IE specific styles?  http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: You can't use paths from local disk.

Comment: Why is `<![endif]-->` nested?

Comment: Remember from IE10 conditional comments are deprecated. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Your conditional comment is right. Do you have more than 31 stylesheets added? http://john.albin.net/css/ie-stylesheets-not-loading

Comment: @Pekka웃 That's useful for an IE specific *overrides* CSS file but it seems OP wants two separate stylesheets

Comment: also Google chrome reads the if !IE tags correctly

Comment: im only using 2 stylesheets, but i found the fix! thank you @skmasq               im using  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785587/if-ie-not-working?rq=1 refer this linl

Answer (score 2):

With the `!IE` condition you should use tags that are not comments:

```
<![if !IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="c:\Users\Saleh\Desktop\Abid\css\stylesheet.css" />
<![endif]>
```

Reference: [About conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.ASPX)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing a tag before the start of the `<![endif]-->` tag

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="c:\Users\Saleh\Desktop\Abid\css\stylesheet.css" />
<!--><![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that newer versions of IE don't support conditional comments anymore as stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Support for conditional comments has been removed in Internet Explorer
>   10 standards and quirks modes for improved interoperability and
>   compliance with HTML5. This means that Conditional Comments are now
>   treated as regular comments, just like in other browsers. This change
>   can impact pages written exclusively for Windows Internet Explorer or
>   pages that use browser sniffing to alter their behavior in Internet
>   Explorer.

To fix this you can use this in `<header>` to emulate conditional comments.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
```