# CSS - Resize image in IE losing resolution (aliasing)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, resize, image-resizing, antialiasing

I have a layout that resizes my images! But I am facing problem of aliasing in Internet Explorer (v.11). I tried some fixes but no success! What can I do to troubleshoot?

[image]

**CSS**

```
li > img.frdImage {
    position: relative;
    margin-top:-25px;
    top:50%;
    float:left;
    margin-left:5px;
    border-radius: 50%;    
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

jsFiddle: [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Igaojsfiddle/MgK6L/34/) (please open using internet explorer)

Answer (score 0):

Use a PHP Image Resize script
Here's an example from PHP.net:

```
<?php
// File and new size
$filename = 'test.jpg';
$percent = 0.5;

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Get new sizes
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$newwidth = $width * $percent;
$newheight = $height * $percent;

// Load
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Resize
imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

// Output
imagejpeg($thumb);
?>
```

Else check this link out:

- http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload_samples.htm

And use `HTTP_USER_AGENT` so that it only resizes when the specified browser is in use

```
<?php
$u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

//First get the platform
if (preg_match('/linux/i', $u_agent)) {
    echo 'linux';
}
?>
```

Hope it helped

Comment: Or take the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` and instead of echoing out the `linux` then make the CSS part there

Comment: It is not necessary php engaged friend, the browser must get the result we want! - Thank you

Comment: Found the solution:
`!--[if !IE]><!--><script src="zepto.min.js"></script><!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]><script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script><![endif]-->`
or take a look at another stackoverflow post:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785587/if-ie-not-working

Comment: Hope it fixed the problem :)

Comment: That depends on js dont only css. Thanks a lot

Comment: It can also be used for CSS, just use the `<link>` tag instead of `<script>`

Comment: Is not that friend. Thx