# Html detect IE8 and lower or any other browser

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

With HTML comments, I am trying to do something like the following -

```
<!-- [if lte IE 8] -->  //if browser is IE8 or less display the following
    <div>IE8</div>    
<!-- [endif] -->

<!-- [if ANY OTHER BROSWER] -->  //any other browser do this
    <div>Any other browser</div>   
<!-- [endif] -->
```

I can't seem to find a combination that works? How can this be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [<!--\[if !IE\]> not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785587/if-ie-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

[Reference](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    According to the conditional comment this is IE 8<br />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    According to the conditional comment this is IE lower than 9<br />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gt IE 7]>
    According to the conditional comment this is IE greater than 7<br />
<![endif]-->
```

For example,

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="my-styles.css">
        <!--[if IE 8]>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="my-ie8-only-styles.css">
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Or you could use it to only render certain html markup...

```
....
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <div id="ie8Only">IE8 Only</div>
<![endif]-->
....
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't seem to handle "run THIS for all browsers besides IE8"

Comment: That would go outside of the conditional comments.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit old question, but here's my solution

```
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><!-->
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if (gte IE 9) | (!IE)]><!-->
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <!--<![endif]-->
```