# else in an IE HTML conditional

Tags: html, internet-explorer

In my site I have an IE HTML conditional like this :

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
      <![endif]-->

..... the rest code of the html page
```

when I run my web page in IE 8 I only want the code inside the condition to be displayed and I dont want to display the rest of the web page.

How can I do that ?

## Edit 1

When I tried this :

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]>

...My code

<![endif]-->
```

It didnt work when I run my web page on `firefox` or `chrome`.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25045631/1398867

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html detect IE8 and lower or any other browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25045565/html-detect-ie8-and-lower-or-any-other-browser)

Comment: @Venugopal I already tried those solution before I wrote this question they didnt work for me the content inside the second IF is not displayed anymore

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use PHP for this action:

```
<?php if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') && preg_match('/(?i)MSIE [6-8]/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) { ?>
<p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
<?php } ?>
```

A faked or filtered HTTP_USER_AGENT on IE is imho very unlikely.

Comment: I know about the php solution but I want in HTML

Answer (score 0):

Adding hyphens (--) makes it a Downlevel-hidden conditional comments which makes downlevel browsers (any browser or browser version that doesn't support conditional comments) ignore the HTML content inside the comment block - if the statement is true

Use the Downlevel-revealed conditional comments instead by removing the hyphens:

```
<![if gt IE 8]>

...Your content

<![endif]>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#dlrevealed