# I want an error page to load if my website is loaded in Internet Exploerer HTML

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I've built my website and it looks fine in chrome, Firefox and basically any web browser other than IE. Does anyone know any code that will direct the user straight to my error page if the user loads the site in IE?

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785587/if-ie-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().search(".net") > -1){

    location.href = "error.html/" //error.html is used as a dummy page. Use your own error page url.

}
```