# Use a specific .js according to the browser

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I just want to know why this does not work :

```html
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="scriptForIE.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

As you can see, I want to use a specific .js according to the browser. I probably made a mistake, I do not understand.

Thanks !

Ps: i'm using IE >= 8

Comment: possible duplicate of [<!--\[if !IE\]> not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785587/if-ie-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

if your trying to target IE8 use

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 8<br />
<![endif]-->
```

see more here

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Answer (score 0):

Thx for your answers.

Finally I've adapted my js code to make it suits for IE and Firefox. I've used this :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

And I've also read that IE => 9 do not recognize anymore the conditions about IE.