# Ignore comment tag for IE doesn't work

Tags: internet-explorer, hide

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFk4K.png)

Screenshot over showing that comment tag that supposed to hide code from IE show this to everyone. Another one that must to hide code for others except IE doesn't show it to anyone.

This answer [<!--[if !IE]> not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785587/if-ie-not-working) didn't helped

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sample example where it may work for you

> This is for until IE9

```
<!--[if IE ]>
    <style> .someclass{
        text-align: center;
        background: #00ADEF;
        color: #fff;
        visibility:hidden;  // in case of hiding
           }
    #someotherclass{
        display: block !important;
        visibility:visible; // in case of visible

    }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

> This is for after IE9

```
  @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
enter your CSS here
}
```