# How can I add a Conditional Comment to my .cshtml MasterPage?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have two css IDs on different files, and I have to change the file with another only when the Program executes in Internet Explorer.
I have this file called "custom.css":

```
#employee-list {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
    border-top: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
    height: initial;
}
```

I need (I must not modify custom.css) to set "height" to "auto". But only if the page is rendered on IE. So I created a second css file called "customie.css":

```
#employee-list {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
    border-top: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
    height: auto;
}
```

After that I wrote this Conditional Comment in the `<head>` of my MasterPage .cshtml.

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="customie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Problem is this: Conditional Comment doesn't work and the customie.css file overwrites the custom.css(which annuls itself) .
How can I apply `height: auto` only for IE pages?

Thank you,
Angelo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [<!--\[if !IE\]> not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13785587/if-ie-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea why the conditional isn't working, but you can achieve the desired effect using the CSS below. IE doesn't support `initial`, so it will fall back to `auto` instead.

```
#employee-list {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
    border-top: 1px solid #c1c1c1;
    height: auto;
    height: initial;
}
```