# Jquery check if browser is IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

How would i check if the users browser is IE? i have this code here but it is not working.

```
if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version <= 9)
{
    alert('You Are Using An Outdated Browser! Switch To Chrome Or FireFox.');   
}
```

Comment: IE conditional comments already exist for this purpose if you insist on browser detection

Comment: You can search a little before ask question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411551/if-browser-is-internet-explorer-run-an-alternative-script-instead

Comment: MSIE is a brand of browser, not a version of browser. Displaying a message declaring it to be "outdated" is nonsensical.

Comment: So if I'm using IE10 I'm using an outdated browser?

Comment: @WillPalmer i understand what you are trying to tell me but i'm just testing some javascript and most of my website isnt compatible with IE so far since i use the new FormData() which it doesnt support.

Comment: @MoussaHarajli [FormData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ie/hh772723(v=vs.85).aspx) is supported as of IE 10!

Comment: @MoussaHarajli - Then it's the FormData functionality you should be testing for, not IE.

Comment: Test for feature support, not browser type.

Comment: also .browser is dropped as of version 1.9

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try [this solution](http://ajaxian.com/archives/attack-of-the-ie-conditional-comment) by James Padolsey:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------
// If you're not in IE (or IE version is less than 5) then:
//     ie === undefined
// If you're in IE (>5) then you can determine which version:
//     ie === 7; // IE7
// Thus, to detect IE:
//     if (ie) {}
// And to detect the version:
//     ie === 6 // IE6
//     ie> 7 // IE8, IE9 ...
//     ie <9 // Anything less than IE9
// ----------------------------------------------------------
var ie = (function(){
    var undef, v = 3, div = document.createElement('div');

    while (
        div.innerHTML = '<!--[if gt IE '+(++v)+']><i></i><![endif]-->',
        div.getElementsByTagName('i')[0]
    );

    return v> 4 ? v : undef;
}());
```

There are other interesting solutions in the comments as well.

Comment: This solution returns `undefined` for IE10

Comment: Microsoft have removed conditional comments for IE10. see http://www.sitepoint.com/microsoft-drop-ie10-conditional-comments/

Answer (score 11):

[`browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) was removed in 1.9.:

> Description: Contains flags for the useragent, read from navigator.userAgent. We recommend against using this property; please try to use feature detection instead (see jQuery.support). jQuery.browser may be moved to a plugin in a future release of jQuery.

Comment: So one would use this check for FormData: `var canFormData = (typeof FormData !== 'undefined');`. There are also feature detection libraries such as [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/).

Answer (score 6):

Test for features, not browsers.  If you use and require FormData like you've stated in your comments, then change your check to:

```
if ( !("FormData" in window) ) {
   // Tell the user to use a better browser, or whatever
}
```

Comment: This is the most accurate way to test if a browser is capable of doing what you need.  You never know when NewBrowserX will come along that may or may not support a feature you need.  This will help you to avoid false positives.

Comment: Browser detection is sometimes useful. For example, `window.onhashchange` exists but doesn't fire on IE 7 and 9.

Answer (score 4):

How about the MS recommended way:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509(v=vs.85).aspx

(And of course the UserAgent can be spoofed... but, if someone is spoofing their UserAgent do you really care about what they see on your site?)

```
 function getInternetExplorerVersion()
 // Returns the version of Internet Explorer or a -1
 // (indicating the use of another browser).
 {
    var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.

    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
    {
        var ua = navigator.userAgent;
        var re  = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");

        if (re.exec(ua) != null) rv = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
    }
    return rv;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a reminder (even thought not directly answers the question); it is always better to user feature detection [as opposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294586/browser-detection-versus-feature-detection) to browser detection.

This is why Modernizr is there for;

> **Why use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)?**
>
> Taking advantage of cool new web technologies is great fun, until you have to support browsers that lag behind. Modernizr makes it easy for you to write conditional JavaScript and CSS to handle each situation, whether a browser supports a feature or not. It’s perfect for doing progressive enhancement easily.

So you would use it like;

`Modernizr.canvas ? showGraph() : showTable();`