# How to detect browser type (not version) using jQuery 1.9 or Javascript?

Tags: jquery, browser-detection

I only need to detect if the browser is Internet Explorer, regardless of version, and add an "IE" class to my document body, using jQuery 1.9 or Javascript.

I want to avoid using plugins like modernizr because it seems overkill for this.

Context: I'm trying to change some SVG CSS3 styles that are set-up for keyframed animations, which IE doesn't support).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery check if browser is IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056620/jquery-check-if-browser-is-ie)

Comment: I'd say you could use IE conditionals to add the `body` tag a la HTML 5 Boilerplate (see the `html` tag`). However, I've just heard IE11 dropped support for conditionals, if that does or doesn't work for you.

Comment: You can also [detect for a vendor-specific `style` property](http://jsfiddle.net/4nFDT/1). Note, you'd probably want to find which vendor-specific style properties work per version of IE; it looks like `msTransform` does for IE9-11. Also, testing it on an SVG could be risky; SVG DOM elements are not the same as HTML DOM elements and things don't always work the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using browser detection you should use feature detection, i.e. use [modernizer](http://modernizr.com/) or some such script on your page. this will cater for all browsers and feature variances.

Comment: While good advice, this doesn't answer the question and should be a comment instead.

Comment: Yeah I thought about modernizr, but a full-fledged feature detection plugin seems overkill for just this single task.

Comment: Actually I don't think modernizr can detect CSS animation support specifically for elements inside an SVG object.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery used to provide `$.browser` but it has been removed in more recent versions of the library. They now suggest that you do what they call "feature detection". Read here:

http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/feature-browser-detection/

And consider using something like modernizr:

http://modernizr.com

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change some CSS style, the best way is probably to add a stylesheet after your normal stylesheets with the overrides you want, and hide it behind an IE conditional comment. Something like this:

```
<head>
  <link src='your normal css' />
  <!--[if lt IE 10]>
  <link src='your IE < 10 css' />
  <![endif]-->
</head>
```

Note I didn't just use `<!--[if IE]>` because you should not detect IE regardless of version. This is a very bad practice that will most probably break your site as future IE gets the features that you want to use.

In fact, you want CSS `animation` (I guess), which is supported unprefixed since IE 10...

Comment: IE10 and higher ignores conditional comments, so this won't work. And while IE does support CSS keyframed animation, it does not support it on elements inside SVG objects.