# Running a javascript IF internet explorer is detected

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip2

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body a[href]').qtip({
        hide: {
            fixed: true,
            delay: 500
        },
        style: {
            classes: 'qtip-dark qtip-shadow'
        },
        position: {
            viewport: $(window)
        }
    });
    jQuery.each(jQuery.browser, function (i, val) {
        $("<div>" + i + " : <span>" + val + "</span>")
            .appendTo(document.body);
    });
});
```

In addition to the above code, how would I run a script ONLY if internet explorer is detected from this browser function? 
The script i want to run if internet explorer is detected is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body a[href]').qtip({
        hide: {
            fixed: true,
            delay: 500
        },
        style: {
            classes: 'qtip-dark qtip-shadow'
        }
    });
```

Comment: note that browser-checking is quiet suboptimal.. as the API points this out too:
Description: Contains flags for the useragent, read from navigator.userAgent. We recommend against using this property; please try to use feature detection instead (see jQuery.support). jQuery.browser may be moved to a plugin in a future release of jQuery.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411551/if-browser-is-internet-explorer-run-an-alternative-script-instead

Comment: @Sirko [Read the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) -- `jQuery.browser` has been deprecated and, in 1.9, completely removed.

Comment: I didnt see that duplicate, and for someone such as myself very new to jquery, etc.. that did not seem to help my specific problem. I apologize if I duplicated tho new to StackOverflow as well. Should I delete this post?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [IE conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
<!--[if IE]>
<script>
// run code here or link to external file
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

They're highly customizable, too -- `<!--[if lt IE 8]>` will only run for IE 7 or below, for instance. Developers use this to create custom stylesheets for IE6/7/8 all the time.

That said, you should really consider using **feature detection** instead of **browser detection** for whatever you're trying to implement. See http://modernizr.com for what is arguably the best solution yet devised.

Comment: Thank you for the help and the link! I will switch to feature detection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript  code to detect

```
//Test for Internet Explorer
if (/MSIE\s([\d.]+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    //Get the IE version.  This will be 6 for IE6, 7 for IE7, etc...
    version = new Number(RegExp.$1);
}
```

Comment: *jQuery.browser* is deprecated since jQuery v1.3. And has been removed completely in v1.9.