# How to show different Exit popup message for IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, popup

I am facing an issue and dont know how to over come from this. I need to show different exit popup for ie. My script is working fine for Chrome and Firefox. It's showing different messages in both browsers. The issue is in IE. I need to show different message in IE but it's not working and by default it showing chrome exit message in IE.

I tried [if-browser-is-internet-explorer-run-an-alternative-script-instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411551/if-browser-is-internet-explorer-run-an-alternative-script-instead)

But than Chrome and Firefox exit pop stop working. here is my website which is working fine it both browsers: http://extremerealestateinvestorsmanual.com/

Is any one have any idea or suggestion to over come from this.??

Comment: Why don't you show the code you are using here in your post!

Comment: Oh you are behind that annoying freaking website!