# Angularjs is not working on some old browser

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, browser

Angularjs scripts are not working on some old browsers so I want to redirect users who use these old browsers. How can I understand angular is working or not in client browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Angular 1.3, support for IE8 and below was dropped

> AngularJS 1.3 has dropped support for IE8. Read more about it on our
>   blog. AngularJS 1.2 will continue to support IE8, but the core team
>   does not plan to spend time addressing issues specific to IE8 or
>   earlier.

you can access the user agent information like so

```
$window.navigator.userAgent;
```

check out this question: [How to detect browser using angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947535/how-to-detect-browser-using-angular)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this script to detect browser and redirect.

```
    $(function() {

    var BrowserDetect = {
            init: function () {
                this.browser = this.searchString(this.dataBrowser) || "Other";
                this.version = this.searchVersion(navigator.userAgent) || this.searchVersion(navigator.appVersion) || "Unknown";
            },
            searchString: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var dataString = data[i].string;
                    this.versionSearchString = data[i].subString;

                    if (dataString.indexOf(data[i].subString) !== -1) {
                        return data[i].identity;
                    }
                }
            },
            searchVersion: function (dataString) {
                var index = dataString.indexOf(this.versionSearchString);
                if (index === -1) {
                    return;
                }

                var rv = dataString.indexOf("rv:");
                if (this.versionSearchString === "Trident" && rv !== -1) {
                    return parseFloat(dataString.substring(rv + 3));
                } else {
                    return parseFloat(dataString.substring(index + this.versionSearchString.length + 1));
                }
            },

            dataBrowser: [
                {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Chrome", identity: "Chrome"},
                {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "MSIE", identity: "Explorer"},
                {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Trident", identity: "Explorer"},
                {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Firefox", identity: "Firefox"},
                {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Safari", identity: "Safari"},
                {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Opera", identity: "Opera"}
            ]

        };

        BrowserDetect.init();

        var browser_url = urlHolder.baseUrl + "browser_update/?browser=" + BrowserDetect.browser + "&version=" +BrowserDetect.version;

        if (BrowserDetect.browser == "Chrome") {
            if (BrowserDetect.version <= "30")
                document.location.href = browser_url
        } else if (BrowserDetect.browser == "Explorer") {
            if (BrowserDetect.version <= "10")
                document.location.href = browser_url
        } else if (BrowserDetect.browser == "Firefox") {
            if (BrowserDetect.version <= "25")
                document.location.href = browser_url
        }
});
```