# Detect browser type and version in AngularJS and display a message if is not supported

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser

I need to detect the browser type and version from where a Angular app is being accessed. I know there are a few JS libraries out there but don't know which one to use.

The web app is supposed to be supported on the latest editions of Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and Internet Explorer.

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22948274/719427) answer but I don't know if is the right way to go, so any advice around this? How I can achieve this?

Comment: Browser detection is a terrible idea. You should check if the browser has the features you desire, not what version it is. For example many "less common" browsers claim to be IE even though they don't have the same feature set as IE.

Comment: can also use IE conditional comments for IE versions <10

Comment: http://srfrnk.github.io/ng-device-detector/

Comment: @stdob-- I get that one you mention from [here](http://srfrnk.github.io/ng-device-detector/) but is not clear to me how to properly shown a message when browser version is less than an specific value, can you provide a little example as a answer?

Comment: you can start your project with initial setup. I recommend to use http://modernizr.com/ to detect your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  `browser not support JavaScript` then you can not display that message using JavaScript you need to use

> `<noscript> Message that has to display </noscript>`

and you can apply css to it

if support and you want to check version using `ng-device-detector` is not possible because it only detect device types, OS types and browser name not version. I found this [article](http://mrbool.com/how-to-detect-different-browsers-and-their-versions-using-javascript/25424) which may help. If you still wanna use `ng-device-detector` here is [GitHub](https://github.com/srfrnk/ng-device-detector) source and this is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/urqMI1?p=preview).

Comment: Can you provide a integration using the example on the link you leave and Angular side? How that works?