# ng-class if browser is not internet explorer

Tags: html, css, angularjs, internet-explorer

I have an issue, i want to add a css class to an item only if the browser isn't internet explorer.

Can I do that with Angular JS?

something like:

```
<div ng-class="myClass : "BROWSER IS IE" ? default"><div>
```

---

SOLUTION:

```
HTML:

       <div data-ng-class="getClass()"></div>

JAVASCRIPT:

        $scope.isIe = function () {
            return false || !!document.documentMode;
        }

        $scope.getClass = function () {
            if ($scope.isIe()) {
                return "";
            }
            else {
                return "yourClass1 yourClass2 yourClass3";
            }
        }
```

Comment: this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947535/how-to-detect-browser-using-angular would help you to how to find browser and then use `ng-class` with method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could assign the class via a function like:

```
data-ng-class="getClass()"
```

In `getClass()` implement functionality to [detect IE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and return the empty string if it is detected, but return a space separated list of class name(s) if it is not. Something like:

**EDIT**: add function isIe based on comment by @jsonmurphy

```
function isIe() {
  return false || !!document.documentMode;
}

$scope.getClass = function() {
  if(isIe()) {
    return "";
  }
  else {
    return "className1 className2 ... ";
  }
}
```

Comment: and how wold you define the isIe() function? this is actually my question

Comment: The answer from @jsonmurphy is one way, or the link I have in my answer to parse the user agent is another. You would do best to use a highly rated method(like the one linked by @jsonmurphy) and just wrap the portion you need to detect IE. Like `function isIe() { return false || !!document.documentMode; }`

Comment: ok so I did as you suggested:  $scope.isIe = function () { return false || !!document.documentMode; }

            $scope.getClass = function () {
                if (isIe()) {
                    return "";
                }
                else {
                    return "form-panel input-lg";
                }
            }

Comment: I didn't scope `isIe`. If you want it scoped change the call in `getClass()` to match as `if($scope.isIe())`

Answer (score 1):

The popular/standard approach to styling for IE is to use [conditional comments](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/internet-explorer-conditional-comments/). In any case, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser) might be of interest to you. Specifically:

```
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode; // At least IE6
```

> **Note**: `isIE` will only detect 6 - 11, not its successor, Edge.

So in your case it might be:

```
<div ng-class="{myClass : (false || !!document.documentMode), default: !document.documentMode}"><div>
```

Hope that helps.