# ng-class for all IE browsers only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

How can I add class to an element if user is opening page in Internet explorer?

```
ng-class="{ie : navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'}"
```

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947535/how-to-detect-browser-using-angular)

Comment: Another related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31678743/ng-class-if-browser-is-not-internet-explorer  - you'd just use the opposite of what they're doing

Answer (score 0):

A basic solution to your problem is, first detect browser and store it to a variable. Then write a conditional expression in your ng-class depending on your browser. Two great related article is already given in the comment section.