# How can I determine mobile browser using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I determine mobile browser using AngularJS? We can detect the browser using JavaScript, just wondering Angular has a different way to detect browser or device.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect browser using angular?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947535/how-to-detect-browser-using-angular)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version of angular:

If in Angular 1 you can use the [$window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947535/how-to-detect-browser-using-angular) object.

That object is gone in Angular 2, however, but there is also [ng-device-detector](https://github.com/srfrnk/ng-device-detector?utm_source=angular-js.in&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=content-curation) which works on Angular 2 and does a decent job at getting device, OS, and browser info.

I would just use pure JS or third party library specifically made for this function. Angular is not meant to replace JavaScript or web/browser APIs, when you try to use angular in unintended ways you often run into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "ng-device-detector" in AngularJS

reference : [here](https://ciphertrick.com/2015/09/21/detect-os-browser-and-device-in-angularjs/)

ngDeviceDetector is a library which help detect the OS, browser and device in AngularJS application with ease.