# Detect if the broswer is IE in SmartGWT

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I want to let the user know if the browser they are using is IE and if so, pop a warning message.

Currently I have the following right before the div IDs are loaded.

```
if(SC.isIE())
{
   SC.warn("You are using IE, please switch")
}
```

but this does not seem to work when I test it with the latest IE. Is there another way to do this (using jQuery), a better way in SmartGWT? or I am putting the `isIE()` at the wrong place. My first choice is doing this using smartGWT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively try with plain GWT by detecting `Window.Navigator.getUserAgent()`

Sample code:

```
public static boolean isIEBrowser() {
    return (Window.Navigator.getUserAgent().toUpperCase().indexOf("MSIE") !=-1);
}
```

---

Note: Please have a look at [User-agent string changes for Internet Explorer 11](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Please read [How to detect IE11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907445/how-to-detect-ie11)

---

IE11 on Windows 8 User agent string

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

IE10 on Windows 8 User agent string:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0)
```

Comment: Unless IE11, in which case test for trident too IIRC.

Comment: @ColinAlworth Thanks a lot I have edited it in my post.

Comment: @Braj so how do I detect 11 using gwt? the link you posted seems to be javascript code only

Comment: You can check `Trident/7.0; rv:11.0` for IE11 in java code itself after getting useragent string using `Window.Navigator.getUserAgent()` or get the idea from the JavaScript and use that logic in Java code