# Active x support in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex

We are working on Active x for a video stream when we install the active x on windows 7 IE 8,9,10 working fine but IE 11 the pop for download is not coming please help regarding the same

Comment: Which ActiveX component are you trying to load? Can you post the HTML that should be triggering it's download?

Comment: if(checkIE())
 {
  player="<OBJECT ID='player' class='lv_player' name='player'  CLASSID='CLSID:FE477AB3-7928-4E5C-8E97-CE2571486BB3' width='"+width+"' height='"+height+"' CODEBASE='DVEWeb.CAB#Version=3.0.0.10' />";
  player=player+"</OBJECT>"; 
 }

Comment: this code working fine for IE 8 to 10 but 11 doest show any popup also

Comment: Can you add the content of checkIE() to your question? That strikes me as very relevant.

Comment: var checkIE=function()
{
 var client = window.navigator.appName;
 if(client == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
 {
  return 1;
 }
 return 0;
 
};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue isn't in the ActiveX as you suspected, but in your detection of Internet Explorer. Your code, from the comments, is:

```
var checkIE=function() {
    var client = window.navigator.appName;
    if(client == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") { return 1; }
    return 0;
};
```

However, IE11 doesn't return `Microsoft Internet Explorer`; according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bg182625(v=vs.110).aspx) it returns `Netscape`. Replace your IE detection with one of the answers from [How to detect IE11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907445/how-to-detect-ie11) instead and you should find your issue solved.