# Javascript - How do i get all the browsers name?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, safari

This is not working when opening on IE11 browser, Safari OSX 10.11. What is wrong?

```
var browser = '';
var browserVersion = 0;

if (/Opera[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    browser = 'Opera';
} else if (/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    browser = 'MSIE';
} else if (/Navigator[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    browser = 'Netscape';
} else if (/Chrome[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    browser = 'Chrome';
} else if (/Safari[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    browser = 'Safari';
    /Version[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent);
    browserVersion = new Number(RegExp.$1);
} else if (/Firefox[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    browser = 'Firefox';
}
if(browserVersion === 0){
    browserVersion = parseFloat(new Number(RegExp.$1));
}
alert(browser + "*" + browserVersion);
```

Outputs: *0 only

Comment: Why do you want to do this? There are many, many browsers that the above will not identify. If it's just for interest, there are databases of user agent strings (e.g. [*user-agents.org*](http://www.user-agents.org), [*useragentstring.org*](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/All/)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need only browser name you can try using this function, this should work for latest IE and Safari:

```
var BrowserDetect = function() {
        var nav = window.navigator,
        ua = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        // Detect browsers (only the ones that have some kind of quirk we need to work around)
        if ((nav.appName.toLowerCase().indexOf("microsoft") != -1 || nav.appName.toLowerCase().match(/trident/gi) !== null))
            return "IE";
        if (ua.match(/chrome/gi) !== null)
            return "Chrome";
        if (ua.match(/firefox/gi) !== null)
            return "Firefox";
        if (ua.match(/safari/gi) !== null)
            return "Safari";
        if (ua.match(/webkit/gi) !== null)
            return "Webkit";
        if (ua.match(/gecko/gi) !== null)
            return "Gecko";
        if (ua.match(/opera/gi) !== null)
            return "Opera";
        // If any case miss we will return null
        return null
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

> IE11 no longer reports as MSIE, according to this list of changes,
> it's intentional to avoid mis-detection.
>
> What you can do if you really want to know it's IE is to detect the
> Trident/ string in the user agent if navigator.appName returns
> Netscape, something like (the untested);

[How to detect IE11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907445/how-to-detect-ie11)

Here's a little more from Microsoft:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537503(v=vs.85).aspx#TriToken

> Trident/7.0   IE11
>
> Trident/6.0   Internet Explorer 10
>
> Trident/5.0   Internet Explorer 9
>
> Trident/4.0    Internet Explorer 8

On the Safari Topic, look at their latest userAgent string, it's does not have ver.ver in it, so you're regex fails on this:

Safari 7.0.3
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 `Safari/7046A194A`