# Identify IE 11 and other browsers

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I know that below code will work for IE 8 and its lower versions.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
Display an image file
<![endif]-->
```

Is there any similar syntax to identify IE 11 and other browsers like Firefox,chrome,..

Below is my prototype.

```
<!--[if IE 11 & other_browsers]>
 Display Chart plugin here
<![endif]-->
```

I need this to display a chart on my web page. IE 11 and other browsers (Firefox,chrome,..) supports it. But IE 8 is not supporting. So I planned to display this chart from IE 11 and other browsers. An image will be displayed for lower version of IE.

For this requirement I am trying **Conditional comment**.

Comment: IE11, but not IE10? Not really. IE10 included? Yes.

Comment: Yes. other way its more than IE8 and other browsers would helpful

Comment: Can you please edit your question with your exact requirements? Because the answer kinda depends on it...

Comment: Cant do this with confitional comments but could use userAgent sniffing? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219582/how-to-detect-my-browser-version-and-operating-system-using-javascript

Comment: @BoltClock updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get ie version by following code-

document.documentMode

so you can implement it like

```
if (document.documentMode==11) {
    // do something
}
```

and for other browsers give document.documentMode==undefined

so you can make this condition as follows:

```
if (document.documentMode==11 || document.documentMode==undefined) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't.

Microsoft [deliberately removed support for conditional comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), and no other browser supported them.

Modern browsers are much better at consistently implementing standards. Distinguishing between them, especially by name, is rarely useful.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907445/how-to-detect-ie11) answering your question:

> Use !(window.ActiveXObject) && "ActiveXObject" in window to detect
>   IE11 explicitly.

Edit: You can use the above test as follows:

```
var isMSIE11 = !(window.ActiveXObject) && "ActiveXObject"
if(isMSIE11) {
//use JS or JQuery to add chart
$('#mydiv').....
}
```

It works only for IE 11. However, depending upon your use case, you might wanna go for feature detection instead of browser detection. As per this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh273397.aspx) article, browser detection has several drawbacks:

> 1. When a new browser is released or an existing browser is updated,
>      you must factor the new browser into your browser detection code.
>      Updated browsers may support standards and features that were not
>      supported when the browser detection code was designed.
> 2. Conclusions about feature support may not be correct or appropriate.
> 3. As new devices become available, they frequently include new versions of
>      browsers; consequently, browser detection code must be reviewed and
>      potentially modified to support the new browsers. In some cases it
>      becomes more complicated to create customized implementations for
>      each browser.
> 4. A browser detection technique may not accurately
>      identify a given browser. For example, many browsers support the
>      ability to modify the user-agent string.

Frameworks such as [modernizer](https://modernizr.com/docs/#what-is-feature-detection) are built just for that.