# Can't activate an event based on JavaScript IE recognition

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to add a textarea resizer plugin on my MVC project, but only for IE, since other browsers have a built-in one. In order to do that I have to check if the browser is IE.

I used the JS from this article:
[How to detect IE11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907445/how-to-detect-ie11)

So this is what I use:

```
function getInternetExplorerVersion() {
    var rv = -1;
    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
        var ua = navigator.userAgent;
        var re = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
        if (re.exec(ua) != null)
            rv = parseFloat(RegExp.$1);
    }
    else if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape') {
        var ua = navigator.userAgent;
        var re = new RegExp("Trident/.*rv:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
        if (re.exec(ua) != null)
            rv = parseFloat(RegExp.$1);
    }
    return rv;
}
function checkVersion() {
    var msg = "You're not using Internet Explorer.";
    var rv = getInternetExplorerVersion();

    if (rv > -1) {
        msg = "You are using IE " + ver;
    }
    alert(msg);
}
```

I inserted it in my scripts folder and I access it through this line in Scripts section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/checkIEVersion.js"></script>
```

Then I try to implement it on pageload:

```
<body onload="checkVersion()">
```

The problem is, nothing happens. I should get an alert, but I get no error, no nothing. When I use only the bottom of the two functions (in the Scripts section with "@(document).ready", it does load correctly.

Could you please assist me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to include this too:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                    window.onload = function () {
                        checkVersion();
                    }
                });
```