# How to target IE10 and below with pure JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

Right now, I'm doing this:

```
if (Function('/*@cc_on return document.documentMode===10@*/ ')()) { 
  // do stuff
}
```

But this only targets IE10. How to do it so I target IE10 and below? (Using the same pure JavaScript method?)

Comment: I think you can check with [`document.documentMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc196988(v=vs.85).aspx) down to IE 8. Although I'm not sure how to check for specific IE versions below that.

Answer (score 1):

You can always parse `UserAgent` string like the old times. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15983064/52317) are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17907562/52317) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19999868/52317) that show you how.

```
function isIE () {
  var myNav = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
  return (myNav.indexOf('msie') != -1) ? parseInt(myNav.split('msie')[1]) : false;
}

if (isIE () && isIE () < 9) {
 // is IE version less than 9
} else {
 // is IE 9 and later or not IE
}
```