# 'onclick' event to open url in new tab or other browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I would like to make a button (with a url) dynamic to what the user's browser is using. If the user is using Chrome, then the link will open in a new tab; however if the user is using IE, the link should open in Chrome.

I am unable to make the following code work in Chrome but this works in IE 9.

I have gotten helpful codes from some other posts.

The following will determine/ check which browser the user is on:

```
function getInternetExplorerVersion()
{
    var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.

    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
    {
        var ua = navigator.userAgent;
        var re  = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
        if (re.exec(ua) != null)
            rv = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
    }

    return rv;
}
```

The above snippet works fine.
My code below works seamlessly in IE but not in Chrome.

```
<input type="button" onclick="openURL()" value="Open Google">

<script>
  function openURL()
  {
      var ver = getInternetExplorerVersion();
      var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");

    if ( ver = -1 )
          shell.run("Chrome www.google.com");
        else
          window.open('www.google.com','_blank');
  }

</script>
```

Comment: try using full url `window.open('http://www.google.com');`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13592045/3163306

Comment: @MantasČekanauskas that's not the problem though

Comment: @avrilalejandro let me try

Comment: Various issues with your code. But first, where/how are you calling checkVersion()

Comment: @yezzz all are inline js, i dont want to use an external .js file.

Comment: @avrilalejandro that might not work as i am using inline js

Comment: Well then I need glasses, .. don't be lazy... reread the code you posted and point me to where you are calling checkVersion()

Comment: @oozmac Simply **chrome** does not read the code

Comment: ok I understand from your edit its not needed

Comment: in other words, getInternetExplorerVersion() will return -1 if it's not IE

Comment: @yezzz that is correct..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome gives an error on that ActiveXObject line, so you should only expose that code to IE. Assuming that `ver` always gives a number other than `-1` in IE you should try this:

```
function openURL() {
  var ver = getInternetExplorerVersion()

  if ( ver != -1 ) {
    // IE
    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    shell.run("Chrome www.google.com");
  } else {
    // other browsers
    window.open('//www.google.com','_blank');
  }
}
```

Of course chrome was reading your code, you just didn't see the error. Press F12 to open the browser dev tools and go to the console tab to see script errors.

Comment: btw, I just checked in IE, and `getInternetExplorerVersion()` also returns -1 in IE... so that code is not reliable. So it seems it only worked in IE because your if -statement was wrong.

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time to solve this case. it works well in **CHROME**. you're the best

Comment: You're welcome. Did you get the getInternetExplorerVersion function fixed? It did not give me correct ver in IE11. Also, the shell.run didn't work, but that's maybe an activeX problem.

Comment: yes, for IE11, the string `Trident/` is now being used, you may refer to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907445/how-to-detect-ie11)

Comment: last question, how do I do it if I want a link to open specifically in IE, just vice versa of my original question? hmmm

Comment: If you mean click a link in chrome will be opened in IE... maybe it's possible somehow, but I don't know. I didn't even know about the IE trick to open link in another browser. I guess that's related to ActiveX.