# Separate javascript for different devices

Tags: javascript, device

Is there a way I can call on different javascript files or lines depending on which device you view the site on? Like media queries for css.

Comment: You could detect the OS based on user agaent and call different functions or even load different js dynamically.

Comment: I think http://davidwalsh.name/device-state-detection-css-media-queries-javascript might help

Answer (score 3):

there are a few general approaches to this:

- [enable features based on browser capabilities](http://html5doctor.com/using-modernizr-to-detect-html5-features-and-provide-fallbacks/)
- check the user agent string on the server and return different scripts
- [detect IE with special comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411551/if-browser-is-internet-explorer-run-an-alternative-script-instead)

I recommend the first approach using modernizr http://modernizr.com/

EDIT:

[detecting a touch aware browser with modernizr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript):
modernizr will add `class="touch'` to the `body`

```
$('.touch #popup).hide() // hide "popup" only on touch devices
```

Comment: I want to make a distinction between touch and non-touch devices, is that possible with Modernizr?

Comment: absolutely http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817029/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-touch-screen-device-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Devices in context of platforms such as android, iphone, ipad, ie mobile etc, we can simply check as:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // here is your javascript code....
}
```

Hope, devices means to be worked as above....