# DIV not pushed down when another div is slided down in IE

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

My page structure is something like this:

```
<header>
<div class="slide">
   <!---- some elements here --->
</div>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li id="open"></li>
        <! --- other parts of the navigation ---->
    </ul>
</nav>
  </header>
   <div class="content">
     <!---- My content goes here ---->
  </div>
<footer>
  <!--- my footer elements --->
</footer>
```

When I click on li with the id=open, the div with class=slide slides down.
The whole header is pushed down with it, but the content div stays over the header's content, that is the header goes under the content div.
This problem appears only in IE, I have tried the following css, but it does not change anything in IE.

CSS:

```
.content{display:block; clear:both; position:relative; top:0; right:0;}
.slide{display:none;background:#ddd;height:130px; width:100%; padding:20px;}
 header{background:#34759a; height:400px; width:100%;}
```

JQuery:

```
$("#open").click(function(){
            $(".slide").slideToggle(300);
            return false;
       });
```

Comment: can you show your `header` and `.slide` css? It would be better if you create a fiddle with your code

Comment: I updated my question. Unfortunately, I don't have time to make a fiddle right now.

Comment: As per the given information it should work.. try setting `position:relative` to header

Comment: I tried it, no change!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of the height of the header, it was set to 400px.
I changed it to 100%. And now IE is behaving! :)

CSS:

```
header{height:100%; width:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

- You could try using CSS3 transitions instead of the jQuery animations
- Instead of `slideToggle()`, you could give the class slide a negative `margin-top` in your css, and then use a jQuery animation to set `margin-top: 0` using `$('.slide').animate({marginTop: 0})`.
- Finally, you can run code only for Internet Explorer if that would help. Take a look at [If Browser is Internet Explorer: run an alternative script instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411551/if-browser-is-internet-explorer-run-an-alternative-script-instead).

Comment: This can't be answer as OP is asking for solution only in IE

Comment: I don't understand, I have suggested some different methods which might work more effectively in IE, and also a way which you could single out IE and manually fix the problem